# Create new function that keeps formatting of its body functions (in R)

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function that describes the number of observations (in a category), the proportions of these categories, and whether any NA's are present, for a categorical variable, with titles/labels for the individual outputs.

In order to get the number of observations and their proportions I am using a function from a package called `gmodels`. It has output visual formatting which I want to keep in my new function, but which is unfortunately changed. This is what I have tried:

I will use these example variable values for this question:

```
gender <- c("male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", NA, "female", "male", "female")
gender <- as.factor(gender)
```

I want my function to run this:

```
CrossTable(gender) #(this is the function from gmodels)
```

Which return this:

```
Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  9 


          |    female |      male | 
          |-----------|-----------|
          |         5 |         4 | 
          |     0.556 |     0.444 | 
          |-----------|-----------|
```

And then I want it to run this:

```
sum(is.na(gender))
```

Which returns this:

```
[1] 1
```

I create my new function:

```
describe_cat <- function(object) {
  CrossTable(object)
  sum(is.na(object))
}
```

And get the expected output

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  9 


          |    female |      male | 
          |-----------|-----------|
          |         5 |         4 | 
          |     0.556 |     0.444 | 
          |-----------|-----------|




[1] 1
```

I want to include titles before each individual output, so that, for example, I know what `[1] 1` refers to. I've tried this function:

```
describe_cat <- function(object) {
  "Observations and Proportions" = CrossTable(object)
  "Any NA's?" = sum(is.na(object))
}
```

But then the output misses the `sum()` function. Then I tried this:

```
describe_cat <- function(object) {
  list(
    "Observations and Proportions" = CrossTable(object),
    "Any NA's?" = sum(is.na(object))
  )
}
```

This time, the output changes the gmodels formatting:

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  9 


          |    female |      male | 
          |-----------|-----------|
          |         5 |         4 | 
          |     0.556 |     0.444 | 
          |-----------|-----------|




$`Observations and Proportions`
$`Observations and Proportions`$t
     female male
[1,]      5    4

$`Observations and Proportions`$prop.row
        female      male
[1,] 0.5555556 0.4444444

$`Observations and Proportions`$prop.col
     female male
[1,]      1    1

$`Observations and Proportions`$prop.tbl
        female      male
[1,] 0.5555556 0.4444444


$`Any NA's?`
[1] 1
```

I suspect the problem is somewhere with the `list()` function. Is there any way to get an output that more or less resembles this?:

```
$`Observations and Proportions`

   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|


Total Observations in Table:  9 


          |    female |      male | 
          |-----------|-----------|
          |         5 |         4 | 
          |     0.556 |     0.444 | 
          |-----------|-----------|



$`Any NA's?`
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CrossTable` returns two outputs, one which is displayed and another which it returns.

The one which you see is the one which is displayed.

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(gender)

#   Cell Contents
#|-------------------------|
#|                       N |
#|         N / Table Total |
#|-------------------------|


#Total Observations in Table:  9 


#          |    female |      male | 
#          |-----------|-----------|
#          |         5 |         4 | 
#          |     0.556 |     0.444 | 
#          |-----------|-----------|
```

The one which it returns is a list which looks like this :

```
temp <- CrossTable(gender)

temp
#$t
#     female male
#[1,]      5    4

#$prop.row
#        female      male
#[1,] 0.5555556 0.4444444

#$prop.col
#     female male
#[1,]      1    1

#$prop.tbl
#        female      male
#[1,] 0.5555556 0.4444444
```

When you store the output in a list it prints the output and returns list output as well. There are other ways to calculate the numbers you are looking for in base R but if you want to maintain the format of `CrossTable` function, you can use

```
describe_cat <- function(object) {
     CrossTable(object)
     c("Any NA's?" = sum(is.na(object)))
}

describe_cat(gender)


#   Cell Contents
#|-------------------------|
#|                       N |
#|         N / Table Total |
#|-------------------------|


#Total Observations in Table:  9 


#          |    female |      male | 
#          |-----------|-----------|
#          |         5 |         4 | 
#          |     0.556 |     0.444 | 
#          |-----------|-----------|




#Any NA's? 
#        1
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak! I had no idea that there were these two outputs for CrossTable